# Rails: `bundle open rails` command not opening rails gem folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, sublimetext3

I'm trying to open rails gem folder using `bundle open rails` command in my local system. For this I have set `export EDITOR='subl -w'` in `.bashrc` file.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work for `rails` gem and when I try to open other gems listed in my Gemfile, it works fine.

- Sublime3
- Ubuntu 12.04

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you run `gem list`, it includes rails ?

Comment: @MarceloBoeira - Yes `gem list` shows `rails`. And it opens empty folder (it is named rails 3.2.22) when I run `bundle open rails`.

Comment: so try to uninstall rails and install it again, removing the folder from you rvm or rvenv ...

Comment: so ? any luck Venkat?

Comment: @MarceloBoeira - No, I am bit concerned uninstall and install rails in my current system. We use Gemset specific to project. I am not sure if this is due to using Gemset.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this behavior you're observing has something to do with how the [Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails) gem is structured - that is, all the logic has been moved into dedicated modules like `ActiveRecord`, `ActionController`, etc. I am seeing the same behavior - `bundle open rails` opens to an empty directory pointing to the gempath - but `bundle open activerecord`, for example, works as expected.

I'm using `export EDITOR = vi` personally, though I don't think it has anything to do with that.